# Lambda Expression in Powershell

Tags: powershell, lambda

I have a code in C# which uses lambda expressions for delegate passing to a method. How can I achieve this in PowerShell. For example the following is a C# code:

```
string input = "(,)(;)(:)(!)";
string pattern = @"\((?<val>[\,\!\;\:])\)";
var r = new Regex(pattern);
string result = r.Replace(input, m =>
    {
        if (m.Groups["val"].Value == ";") return "[1]";
        else return "[0]";
    });
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

And this is the PowerShell script without the lambda-expression in place:

```
$input = "(,)(;)(:)(!)";
$pattern = "\((?<val>[\,\!\;\:])\)";
$r = New-Object System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex $pattern
$result = $r.Replace($input, "WHAT HERE?")
Write-Host $result
```

**Note:** my question is not about solving this regular-expression problem. I just want to know how to pass a lambda expression to a method that receives delegates in PowerShell.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

In PowerShell 2.0 you can use a script block (`{ some code here }`) as delegate:

```
$MatchEvaluator = 
{  
  param($m) 

  if ($m.Groups["val"].Value -eq ";") 
  { 
    #... 
  }
}

$result = $r.Replace($input, $MatchEvaluator)
```

Or directly in the method call:

```
$result = $r.Replace($input, { param ($m) bla })
```

**Tip:**

You can use `[regex]` to convert a string to a regular expression:

```
$r = [regex]"\((?<val>[\,\!\;\:])\)"
$r.Matches(...)
```

Comment: And thanks also for mentioning the `param($m)` syntax inside the script-blocks.

Comment: If anyone would like a real example: `$repo.Deployments.FindOne({ param($d) $d.EnvironmentId -eq $envId });`

Answer (score 31):

Sometimes you just want something like this:

```
{$args[0]*2}.invoke(21)
```

(which will declare an anonymous 'function' and call it immediately.)

Answer (score 18):

You can use this overload

```
[regex]::replace(
   string input,
   string pattern, 
   System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchEvaluator evaluator
)
```

The delegate is passes as a scriptblock (lambda expression) and the MatchEvaluator can be accessed via the $args variable

```
[regex]::replace('hello world','hello', { $args[0].Value.ToUpper() })
```

Comment: Can you use a ScriptBlock in place of any delegate? Where is this documented?

Comment: Generally speaking, yes. I'm not aware of any documentation.

Comment: Thanks this works. And +1 for mentioning the `$args` array inside the script block.

Comment: Thanks! Alternatively you can define named parameters with the param keyword.