# Powershell Regular Expressions getting values out of a -replace match

Tags: regex, powershell, replace, multiple-matches

I want to take each number in a string and replace it with its doubled value.
For instance "1 2 3 4 5 " should become "2 4 6 8 10" or "4 6 10 " should be "8 12 20"

I think I'm nearly there, however, I can't seem to get the value out of the match
I've tried using '$1' or '\1' but neither worked correctly.

```
function doubleIt($digits = "1 2 3 4 5 ")
{
$digit_pattern = "\d\s+"
$matched = $digits -match $digit_pattern

if ($matched)
{
    $new_string = $digits -replace $digit_pattern, "$1 * 2 "
    $new_string
}
else
{
    "Incorrect input"
}
}
```

-Edit: Thanks for the help. I would like to know the Regular Expression method for my knowledge encase I end up with something unrelated later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a script block as the MatchEvaluator delegate as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10996050/20938).  To answer your question:

```
[regex]::replace('1 2 3 4 5 ','\d+', { (0 + $args[0].Value) * 2 })

> 2 4 6 8 10
```

`$args[0]` contains the Match object (not the MatchEvaluator as the author said in the other answer), so `$args[0].Value` is equivalent to `matchObject.Groups[0].Value`.

Comment: Nice. I did replace '1 2 3 4 5 ' with $digits and manually casted without the 0+. Hope that wasn't wrong.. Works well.

Comment: Whatever works.  I don't use PowerShell, so I don't know its idioms.  The `0 +` trick was just the first thing I tried that worked.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Split the string and cast valid values to integers.

```
function doubleIt($digits = "1 2 3 4 5")
{
    #[string](-split $digits -as [int[]] | ForEach-Object {$_*2})
    [string](-split $digits | where {$_ -as [int]} | foreach {2*$_} )
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was kinda hoping for the way to do it with a regular expression encase I need to pull the data out later.. or save it or something.

Comment: @TrevorTiernan Just save Shay's function output to a variable and you can operate on the new string (and contents) however you like.  What benefit are you expecting some other regex solution to afford you?

Comment: No I meant like saving '$_' which I suppose I could just do. I suppose I was wondering how to get the value out of a current match... Edit: Oh, one problem I just run into, was that the content is not verified. Therefore if I have a string like "a 1 2 3" it doesn't become "a 2 4 6"

Comment: @TrevorTiernan I updated the function and commented out the old one. Does it work for you now?

Comment: What I'm wanting is a Regular Expression means of getting the current match. Similar to the $1 in my original code. This is being asked more as an academic exercise, not purely for the solution. Basically I want to be able to find and replace. So I could have "My name is '@'sam '@'trevor 123 bob '@'fred" and be able to replace (using a different regular expression) everything that comes after a '@' with say some other list of names like 'ted' or 'frank' essentially 'insert regular expression' 'insert change function' 'get new string'

Comment: I suggest you open a new thread and elaborate as a much as you can, with a specific use case, so we can better understand the goal and be precise with our answers.