# Using nested lambda expression in PowerShell

Tags: c#, linq, powershell, sharepoint, lambda

There is a good solution available **[at Github](https://gist.github.com/glapointe/cc75574a1d4a225f401b)** and **[SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34336300/how-do-i-do-a-lambda-expression-in-powershell)** about how to use C# lambda expressions equivalent in PowerShell.

As per the example is given, I managed to form the simple working lambda equivalent for my C# snippet as below:

```
ctx.Load(web, s => s.Id);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
// 'ctx' is Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext
// 'web' is ctx.Web -> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web
```

When using in PowerShell → this is working fine.

```
Load-CSOMProperties -Object $clientContext.web -PropertyNames @("Id")
$clientContext.ExecuteQuery()
```

However, I am unable to convert the nested lambda expression, I tried some variations, but unable to figure it out what I am missing:

```
ctx.Load(web.Webs, w => w.Include(s => s.ServerRelativeUrl));
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
// web.Webs is WebCollection; s is Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web
```

When using in PowerShell

```
Load-CSOMProperties -ParentObject $clientContext.web -CollectionObject $clientContext.web.Webs -PropertyNames @("ServerRelativeUrl") -ParentPropertyName "Include"
$clientContext.ExecuteQuery()
```

I am getting the below exception:

```
    An error occurred while enumerating through a collection: The collection has not
    been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed.
    It may need to be explicitly requested..
    At D:\Test.ps1:122 char:17
    +             if ($collectionObject -ne $null) {
    +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Share...int.Client.Web]:d__0) [], RuntimeException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadEnumeration Exception calling "Property" with "2" argument(s): "Instance property 'Include' is not defined for type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web'"
    At D:\Test.ps1:137 char:13
    +             $collectionProperty = [System.Linq.Expressions.Expression ...
    +             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentException   Exception calling "Call" with "3" argument(s): "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: arguments"
    At D:\Test.ps1:144 char:13
    +             $callMethod = [System.Linq.Expressions.Expression]::Call( ...
    +             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentNullException   Exception calling "Invoke" with "2" argument(s): "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: body"
    At D:\Test.ps1:146 char:13
    +             $expression2 = $lambdaMethodGeneric2.Invoke($null, @($cal ...
    +             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentNullException
```

My next few lines in PowerShell are:

```
foreach ($subsite in $clientContext.web.Webs) {
    Write-Host "Subsite :" $subsite.ServerRelativeUrl
}
```

I think the nested lambdas can be broken into two `ExecuteQuery()`, but not sure how.

Comment: Your question should have the minimum code required to try this, ctx is not defined here...

Comment: @AustinTFrench: Unable to edit the question, stuck due to some formatting issue -> *ctx is Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext*